# The app needs to be configured to android Tablets only from Google play store

Tags: codenameone

Please suggest the setting or build hints which is show as "Designed for Android Tablets" on Google Play store.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following build hints:

```
android:smallScreens=false
android:normalScreens=false
```